# Which should I use Handler, AsyncTask or Thread?

Tags: android

This may be a common question but I couldn't find my exact scenario. I understand that its down to developer choice in a lot of ways but I don't know enough to choose best.

I have my initial app splash screen which will just display a logo whilst checking the user is logged in. If their login details are already stored in a sharedPreference then I want to check those details against my online database of details for verification. Once this is all checked I'll either pass the user through to the main app screen or a registration screen.

So when doing this check of user details, and then verifying them. Should I do this in a separate or use a handler? I don't think AsyncTask is needed as I'm not wanting to pass any progress details back to the UI?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using AsyncTask.

First of all, because AsyncTask is a complete threading framework (that uses Thread and Handlers behind the scenes) that allows for a nicer control of single thread operations. Including `cancel()` for example, in case the user decices to leave the application before the splash screen is done.

> I don't think AsyncTask is needed as I'm not wanting to pass any
>   progress details back to the UI?

actually, yes you do, even to start the new activity (either Login or AlreadyLoggedIn) you have to call startActivity() from the UI thread

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do this in a separate thread because it is network activity. `IntentService` is a good option. I think your main concern is that whatever method you choose needs to work even if the user rotates the screen and the activity is destroyed and recreated.

Maybe use a Fragment for the splash screen with `setRetainInstance(true)`, so it will get reattached to the activity after configuration change. Then you can either pass the service a `Handler` (or a `Messenger` to be more accurate), or have the service send out a broadcast intent when it finishes working.

Answer (score 1):

**When to use an Async Task?**

AsyncTask helps in offloading memory intensive/blocking call to a background thread while, your UI operations can still carry on in the UI thread. 
If any operation blocks the UI thread for more than 4-5secs, you might also get an ANR(Android Not Responding) dialog. AsyncTask come handy when you want to update the UI after doing the process (`onPostExecute`) and also before starting it (`onPreExecute`).

**Using a Thread**
Whatever you do in `doInBackground` using an AsyncTask can also be achieved using a Thread. But incase you need to do any UI operation you will need to use a `Handler` or `runOnUiThread` to accomplish your task. Refer to [Painless Threading in android](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html) in case you wish to use threads.

Also what Budius said is true.

In your case you can use an AsyncTask to check for user creds in sharedPref and then appropriately authenticate with your middleware and finally in onPostExecute navigate to a new activity.

In the meanwhile you can show a progress bar to the user signifying the on going auth process.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to that. I had a very similar situation where I had to verfiy a users login (which was stored in the phone) in the background from a "home screen". I used the IntentService ResultReceiver pattern. At first it took a bit for me to get up-to-speed on it, but once its implemented its very simple to manage.

Basically, you start the activity that is your intent service, passing it any parameters that are needed (username, password, etc...). In my case it was a separate class that used REST to verify the user. Once the REST class has done its work, the ResultReceiver method onReceiveResult, returns back the data to the UI activity from the REST activity.